# UITextField binding to a decimal. Can I automatically turn empty string to zero

Tags: uitextfield, mvvmcross

I have a very standard binding set up in android on a UITextView

```
local:MvxBind="Text Quantity"
```

Where Quantity is an int property.

If I enter 123 say, that gets assigned and the setter is called. As I delete that text, 123 -> 12 -> 1 -> empty string, the setter is called for each number but not for the empty string infact the following exception occurs:

```
MvxBind:Error: 48.84 SetValue failed with exception - FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
```

Is there a way of automatically converting the empty string value to 0 in the binding? Will I need a value converter for this? Is this in fact a bug?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This area has been discussed recently in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/350 with some `nullable` additions in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/373 - people are welcome to contribute their opinions (and/or code) there.

The current 'status quo' is that MvvmCross will parse and represent valid decimal numbers. However, if the number isn't valid - eg if it's string.Empty or a set of non-numeric characters - then MvvmCross won't interpret these as zero (should "" be zero? should "asdf" be zero? should "123.456.7" be zero? should "1234asd" be zero? perhaps all of these should actually be `NaN`?).

If people need specific behaviour then it's easy for them to implement this behaviour - e.g. using a custom control (subclassed UITextField), using a value converter, using a custom binding (or overriding the default binding), using a string property on the viewModel, etc.

My personal opinion is that this topic really comes under the `Validation` heading. In general, MvvmCross doesn't provide many hooks for `Validation` at present. It's been proposed for a long time - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/133 - but no-one has shown much interest. There are some simple validation samples in the WithErrors demo within https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/ApiExamples. Within the apps I've written we've generally written and sub-classed UI controls to help reduce the need for validation - and in general we've tried to avoid the need for as much text input as we can (users don't like seem to like using keypads on phones)

Comment: Thank you once again. I have gone with the Value Converter solution although I feel perhaps the subclassed UITextField is more appropriate. I also agree that free text for numerical values is not ideal and perhaps a spinner is better.